# Problems with using vertex attribute value in opengl es 2.0

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader

I am struggling for days and i still can't figure out what i am doing wrong. 
I have a vertex attribute consisting of a single float and i want to compare it's value with other in an if statement but i always get the statement true even if it is not;
Here is my vertex shader were the problem occur:

```
attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec3 a_Normal;
attribute vec2 a_TextureCoord; 
attribute highp float a_Bone;
uniform mat4 bone_1; 
uniform mat4 bone_0; 
varying vec2 v_TextureCoord; 
void main() { 
  v_TextureCoord = a_TextureCoord; 
  vec4 posy;
  float a = a_Bone;
  if(20.0<a) 
     posy = bone_0*a_Position;
  else 
     posy = bone_1*a_Position;
  gl_Position = posy; 
  }
```

if i replace what is in if statement with "true" or "false" all the things work as expected ...but if i'm trying to use that attribute value for comparing the if statement acts as the statement is always true even if when a_Bone value is 1.0 or 2.0 (clearly smaller the 20.0)

Comment: Would you provide more information likes how you pass the uniform variable and vertex attribute codes?

Comment: yes ...all the vertex attributes are stored in a vbo..

Comment: GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_bone);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(a_bone,1, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, stride,
                    (position_count +normal_count+texCoord_count)*bytes_per_float);  this way I do the passing of data

Comment: The problem is not with passing the data because it successfully renders when i remove if statement and i also tried replacing a_Bone from if statement with a_Position.x  and same results

Answer (score 0):

We've been using `Attributes` in the if statemens and the code is working fine on most OpenGL ES 2.0 devices. So it is not a problem in using attributes. Here is a working code of how we have done.

```
int jointId = int(optionalData1.x);
if(jointId > 0)
    finalMatrix = jointTransforms[jointId - 1] * optionalData2.x;
```

This code is working fine on all iOS and Android devices. `optionalData1` is the attribute and we are even using this value to get matrix from a uniform array for bone transform matrix.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i have tried that with no succes... I also tested on multiple devices (Samsung, Htc) and multiple android version 4.4, 5.1,6.0 ...with no succes